# How to split TensorFlow graph (model) onto multiple GPUs to avoid OOM?

Tags: tensorflow

So I have this very large and deep model I implemented with TensorFlow r1.2, running on an NVIDIA Tesla k40 with 12 GB of memory. The model consists of several RNNs, a bunch of weight and embedding matrices as well as bias vectors. When I launched the training program, it first took about 2-3 hours to build to model, and then crashed due to OOM issues. I tried to reduce batch size to even 1 data sample per batch, but still ran into the same issue.

If I google `tensorflow muitlple gpu`, the examples I found mainly focused on utilizing multiple GPUs by **parallel** model design, which means to have each GPU run the ***same*** graph and have the CPU calculate the total gradient thus propagate back to each parameters.

I know one possible solution might be running the model on an GPU with larger memory. But I wonder if there's a way to **split** my graph (model) into different parts **sequentially** and assign them to different GPUs?

Answer (score 1):

The official guide on [using GPUs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu) shows you that example in "Using multiple GPUs". You just need to create the operations within different [`tf.device`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/device) contexts; the nodes will still be added to the same graph, but they will be annotated with device directives indicating where they should be run. For example:

```
with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
    net0 = make_subnet0()
with tf.device("/gpu:1"):
    net1 = make_subnet1()
result = combine_subnets(net0, net1)
```